# Removing line breaks between 2 different character sequences

Tags: php, regex, csv, delimiter, preg-replace-callback

I'm editing a csv file which contains hidden line breaks. When I apply the following php script, the line breaks are successfully removed from the entire file.

```
$csvFileNew = str_replace(array("\r", "\n"), '', $csvFileOld);
```

But I only want to remove these line breaks from within certain sections of the file - between all occurrences of the following (enclosed in single quotes):

```
$start = ',""';
$end = '",';
```

My current script looks like this:

```
$csvFileOld = "pre text appears here....,\"\"key words appear here\"\",....post text appears here";
//line break always appears between the final 2 quotation marks

$csvFileNew = preg_replace_callback('`,""([^"]*)",`', function($matches)
    {
        return str_replace(array("\r", "\n"), '', $matches[1]);

    },$csvFileOld);
```

Unfortunately, this script doesn't remove the line break - I'm assuming the regex I've used doesn't grab enough. Can anyone suggest an elegant solution?

I know it won't be possible for answers to include a working example because of the line break, however I'm really just after a solution which grabs the correct content between the delimiters.

Comment: What is wrong with the current solution?

Comment: Are you trying to replace line breaks that are part of any column value? Then you should use `fgetcsv` to _properly_ read each line into an array, replace the line breaks inside the array elements, and write the whole line back via `fputcsv`. No messing around with regex.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I've edited my question accordingly. My regex doesn't seem to grab the content where the line break is.

Comment: You have 2 `"`s followed with a comma. So, you need ``'`,""([^"]*)"",`'``. Or maybe just ``'`,""(.*?)",`s'``, see https://3v4l.org/3WmvU

Comment: @CBroe The vast majority of line breaks in the csv file are correctly handled by the rest of my script. It's just these occasional ones which I was hoping to edit quickly. They seem to be a result of manual entry error at the xls file stage - something I have no control over. Thanks for the suggestion though - I may need to look into this further.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your can use

```php
<?php

$csvFileOld = "pre text appears here....,\"\"key\n\n words\r\n appear\r\n here\"\",....post text appears here";
//line break always appears between the final 2 quotation marks

$csvFileNew = preg_replace_callback('`,""(.*?)",`s', function($matches)
{
    return str_replace(array("\r", "\n"), '', $matches[1]);
},$csvFileOld);
echo $csvFileNew;
```

See the [PHP demo](https://3v4l.org/FNKSV).

The `,""(.*?)",` regex now matches from `,""` till the first occurrence of `",` substring.

The `s` flag is added to allow dots to match across lines.